# Add tags to pages

Tags: theme-development, tags

I'd like to be able to add tags to my pages just like I can with posts.

What would I need to do to enable the tag editor/entry for the page editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type) function.

The following adds the default 'tag' and 'category' taxonomies to pages:

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'page');
register_taxonomy_for_object_type('category', 'page');
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This works! I assume there's no need to use add_meta_box('tagsdiv-post_tag', __('Page Tags'), 'post_tags_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'low');

Comment: Nope, just the above.